# How to typeset this optimization problem in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

How can I reproduce this formatting of an optimization problem (just the "minimize t subject to ..." part; I included the text around it for context) in LaTeX? I tried using the `align*` environment but couldn't get it to work. Either the justification is wrong, or the spacing between the texts and equations is too wide.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related.

Comment: There exists a package dedicated to this specific layout problem: `optidef`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `optidef` package.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nocomma]{optidef}

\begin{document}

The \emph{epigraph form} of the standard problem \eqref{st-prob} is the problem
\begin{mini}[2]
{}{t}{}{}
\addConstraint{f_0(x)-t}{\le 0}
\addConstraint{f_i(x)}{\le0\quad}{i=1,\dots,m}
\addConstraint{h_i(x)}{=0}{i=1,\dots,p,}
\end{mini}
with variables $x\in\mathbf{R}^n$ and $t\in\mathbf{R}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The row spacing is better than with a plain tabular

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a `tabular` environment inside an `equation`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\noindent
The \textit{epigraph form} of the standard problem is the problem
\begin{equation}
    \begin{tabular}{rl}
        minimize & $t$\\
        subject to & $f_0(x) - t \le 0$\\
                   & $f_i(x) \le 0$, \quad $i=1, \dots, m$\\
                   & $h_i(x) = 0$,   \quad $i=1, \dots, p$,\\ 
    \end{tabular}
\end{equation}
with variables $x\in R^n$ and \dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With `array` or `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

With \verb+array+  \eqref{eq:array}:
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:array}
\begin{array}{rl}
    \text{minimize} & t\\
  \text{subject to} & f_0(x) - t \le 0\\
                    & f_i(x) \le 0, \quad i=1, \dots, m\\
                    & h_i(x) = 0,   \quad i=1, \dots, p,
\end{array}
    \end{equation}
with variables $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. We can easily see \dots

\medskip
or with \verb+split+ \eqref{eq:split}:
    \begin{equation}\label{eq:split}
\begin{split}
    \text{minimize} \quad   & t\\
  \text{subject to} \quad   & f_0(x) - t \le 0\\
                            & f_i(x) \le 0, \quad i=1, \dots, m\\
                            & h_i(x) = 0,   \quad i=1, \dots, p,
  \end{split}
    \end{equation}
with variables $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. We can easily see \dots

\end{document}
```

[image]